# Why has someone copied my website, and why is it showing up as a referral in GoAccess?

Tags: nginx, copy

I recently created a simple website to serve as a resume. I run it off of a VM that I configured myself with Ubuntu and Nginx. I also installed a tool called GoAccess that allows me to see things like referring sites and the number of unique visitors. I was looking at the logs today and noticed that there was a referring site with a domain that I had never heard of. I entered the URL into my web browser and was surprised to find an exact copy of my website, images and all. Is this necessarily nefarious? Does it indicate that my web server is insecure? As far as I can tell it's just an exact copy of my website, but I'm worried about potential abuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably nefarious - although who knows the copiers intent, and there is likely very little you can do about it, other then keep an eye on it and make sure your site remains canonical in Googles eyes.

You have done nothing wrong, and nothing in your post implies your website is insecure.

Some things you can do to mitigate this kind of thing -

- You have not mentioned if you use HTTPS - if not, you should add it.
- If your site uses PHP (or an equivalent framework which allows server side scripting), you may be able to do things (like put the date on it, generated by PHP) in a future version of your site.
- Its almost certainly not worthwhile, but you could always try trace down the host for that site and ask them to pull it down on copyright grounds.
- Watermark your images with the canonical address of your site.